# Where did the Christians in Hebrews 10:25 have their assemblies?

Tags: history, hebrews

Do we know where the Christians in Hebrews 10:25 had their assemblies (for example, synagogues, private houses)?

[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Hebrews%2010%3A25/):

> not neglecting to meet together, as is the habit of some, but
>   encouraging one another, and all the more as you see the Day drawing
>   near.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to go out on a limb and say no we don't know where the Christians in Hebrews 10:25 had their assemblies.

There appears to be no internal or external evidence to suggest this passage implies a particular type or size of meeting.

The reason for this answer is that reputable commentaries aren't even on agreement on the matter of who Hebrews was written to. If there is no consensus on who the letter itself is written to, then we don't know enough about the readers to give a concrete answer.

From NIVAC:

> The highly influential church at Antioch in Syria, with its large Jewish-Christian and Gentile contingents (cf. Acts 11:19–26; 13:1–3), has often been recognized as the original recipients of the Gospel. This is confirmed in part because of its influence on Ignatius the bishop of Antioch and on the Didache. But Matthew’s message was equally relevant for the fledgling church throughout the ancient world and appears to have been disseminated fairly quickly.

---

*That said, I believe that there would be some great well informed opinions on the matter, but your question does not ask for opinions. Just because there is no common consensus doesn't mean that you can't come to a conclusion on the answer for yourself. If you can reveal a little more about your motive for the question (what makes you want to ask this question) then an answer that speaks to that issue may be possible.*

Comment: I am aware that there were meetings held at synagogues, temple and people's homes. Later on in underground caves and buildings. Given that Hebrews 10:25 does not especifically say where those Christians met, I wanted to know if there is some piece of historical background that may provide something on this....

Comment: …. With all this, correct me if I am wrong, the text seems to support that “not neglecting to meet together” is not restricted to one particular place, but the necessity for Christians to meet together somewhere. In today's context, Christians meet in church buildings, chapels, university and college dorm rooms, homes, and those under persecution in some places meet together underground.

Comment: I agree with the idea that the passage is not prescriptive or descriptive of a particular mode or size of meeting. As in my answer, there appears to be no external or internal evidence that would suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob is correct that the audience is *somewhat* of a mystery (though we do know quite a bit about them), but incorrect that this leaves us unable to answer your question.

The New Covenant believers addressed in Hebrews met in homes (as did every other New Covenant congregation prior to the 3rd century). They met over a meal, sometimes called the "love feast", "the Lord's supper", or "the table of the Lord". This was a *covenant* meal. Over the course of a couple thousand years this morphed into what we now know as "communion" (a crouton and juice snack consumed in a local "church" building), but in the first century it was a meal taken together in homes.

It is true that the very first Jewish converts continued to go to the synagogue as well for the very short period of history that they were allowed, but this was not the gathering of the New Covenant community; it was more transitional and evangelistic in nature. To these early converts, synagogue participation did not *replace* the gathering of the New Covenant community; it was a separate activity, and so they *also* gathered regularly with fellow New Covenant believers (in homes, over a meal.)

It is the gathering of the New Covenant community (which took place over a meal in homes) that the author of Hebrews is referring to.

---

Note that this does not necessarily answer the question of whether New Covenant believers today should *also* meet in homes over a meal; it simply answers the question of what the gathering of the New Covenant community *in the first century* looked like.